# Skype4com automation - How to get list of participants on a call

Tags: c#, .net, skype, skype4com

I'm trying to write an application that talks to Skype to do a few things. One thing I'd like to do, is when a voice call connects, obtain a list of the participants.

I'm doing this currently by registering for the `Skype.CallStatus` event. When triggered, this event handler gets a `Call` argument, which has a `Participants` property. Currently, however,  that list of participants is empty (I'm testing by calling the Skype voice testing service).

Is there any reason why that would be? Is there another way to get the list of participants on a call?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can get a list of participants (please, note that I haven't tried hard) is through **ICall.PartnerDisplayName** property (you'll need to collect the partner names as Skype raises *CallStatus* event multiple times).

**[edit]**

The skype4com documentation for the **Participants** property states:

> This command queries the number of participants in a conference call **not hosted by the user**.

After reading this I've done a test: start a group call from another machine; in this case the participants list is correct.

A usefull sample on how to use Skype4com:  http://skype.codeplex.com

**[/edit]**

Hope this helps